# i have a strange bug with collision, is there any way around this or do i have to pick a different method?

Tags: java, collision-detection, javafx

so lately i've been learning about abstract classes and interfaces, and i saw a neat yt video about falling sand games (think Noita) so i wanted to take a crack at it as some particles share a characteristic that can be abstracted, and behavior that's not specific to only particles that can be interfaced. only going to be implementing 2, maybe 3 types of "particle" but it seems im having trouble with gravity.

i've spent a few hours trying to figure out a good way of doing it and this is what i got so far out of my attempts (which include: gravity somehow working backwards, collision being ignored, and working, but sunk a few pixels into the object)

```
// the drop method is called every second, and force == 1
// drop is a method from the Gravity interface, Sand implements gravity and overrides drop.

@Override
public void drop(Particle self) {
    for (Particle p : Controller.particle) {
        if (p.equals(self)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (self.rectangle.getBoundsInParent().intersects(p.rectangle.getBoundsInParent())) {
            Behavior.repulseUpward(self, force);
        }
    }
    Behavior.gravityDrop(self, force);
}

public class Behavior {
    static void gravityDrop(Particle p, double force) {
        // in the future ill replace bottomLine with what's inside it but for now its more
        // readable to me.
        double bottomLine = (Controller.height - p.rectangle.getHeight());
        if (p.rectangle.getLayoutY() < bottomLine) {
            p.setPosition(p.rectangle.getLayoutX(), p.rectangle.getLayoutY() + force);
        }
    }

    static void repulseUpward(Particle p, double force) {
        p.setPosition(p.rectangle.getLayoutX(), p.rectangle.getLayoutY() - force);
    }
}
```

(if i've forgotton any code that you think would be relevant ill add it)

this gives me the behavior i was hoping for! exceeeeeept if say two shapes are 20 pix wide, and are spaced 20 pix apart, it will still detect a collision and cause themselves to suspend in air. Is there any fix to get around this situation or do i have to scrap the drop method again?

Picture of the problem [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWSx3.jpg)

Comment: Am I understanding from your picture that the red square should fall between the black and white squares, but is prevented from doing so because the corner-to-corner point contact counts as a collision that holds it up?

Comment: all three of those squares are meant to fall, they are holding each other up because it seems that despite not overlapping, they are counted as such.